# DynamoDB createTable if not exists

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Hi need to create a table on DynamoDB. The problem is, if it exists `createTable` response is an error. How do i avoid that. Because I throw a notification when error occurs, but in this case, I don't want to.

I don't want to compare the error code because `ResourceInUseException` is too vague for it. Also, I don't think sending a describe table request first is really a proper solution.

Is there any way to `createIfNotExists`?

Comment: You can list existing tables. Maybe from that you can check? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.html#WorkingWithTables.ListingAndDescribing

Comment: You either have to catch the error and examine it, or perform some call like `describeTable` or `listTables` before attempting to create the table. There is no "if table not exists" functionality in DynamoDB.

Comment: Was just looking into this myself. I might just do the listTables option as mentioned by matsev. But this is pretty ghetto that there's no way to do this already, or there's not standard error code for us to check.

Answer (score 11):

Since you don't like [describeTable()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#describeTable-property) then I guess that [listTables()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#listTables-property) is your only option, e.g.

```
const tableName = // ...
const tablePromise = dynamodb.listTables({})
    .promise()
    .then((data) => {
        const exists = data.TableNames
            .filter(name => {
                return name === tableName;
            })
            .length > 0;
        if (exists) {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
        else {
            const params = {
                TableName: tableName,
                // more params
            }; 
            return dynamodb.createTable(params).promise();
        }
    });
```

Note, if you have more than 100 tables, the result will be paged and you must call `listTables()` repeatedly, see `ExclusiveStartTableName` and `LastEvaluatedTableName` in the [api docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#listTables-property) for details.

Answer (score 4):

One other possible solution could be to check the err.code and err.message. The "err.message" gives you the exact reason.

```
if (err.code === "ResourceInUseException" && err.message === "Cannot create preexisting table") {
        console.log("message ====>" + err.message);
    } else {
        console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)); 
    }
```

Comment: Well, I'm already doing that. Sorry i should've mentioned it. The problem is, it might break if they change the string. Like `ResourceInUseException` to `ResourceAlreadyExistsException`